# Classifying a list of documents

Tags: python, python-2.7, classification, nltk, corpus

I'm trying to retrieve documents in multiple directories and classify them. The [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html) shows the example for categorizing files in two folders within the movie_reviews corpus, 'pos' and 'neg':

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
              for category in movie_reviews.categories()
              for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
```

I attempted to do something similar for a couple of folders within the same directory:

```
reviews= "C:\Users\Alpine\Documents\Reviews" #Folders: Good, Bad
documents = [(list(reviews.words(fileid)), category)
              for category in reviews.categories()
              for fileid in reviews.fileids(category)]
```

However I get `Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'categories'` at `for category in reviews.categories()`.

Is this method exclusive for files in the nltk corpus? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in confusing `movie_reviews` and `reviews`

`movie_review` is defined by importing from `nltk.corpus` and has a method `words`.

`reviews` is a variable to which you have assigned a string. And the string does not have a method `words`, as you were told by the error message.